# Does Xamarin IOS Simulator Require XCode?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Well , im new to IOS app development i've heard about Xamarin cross-platform app-development, so my setup is ==>

1. Visual Studio Enterprise Update 1 Installed.
2. Xamarin For Visual Studio 2015 Downloaded (Now about to install).
3. Xamarin IOS simulator downloaded.

Now as i have xamarin simulator i don't need to buy a mac or get a hosted-mac , that's clear now i just wanna confirm do i need XCode ? i mean i have xamarin simulator but still i'm confused about XCODE for windows how can i get that should it be getting installed automatically or do i need to give it another shot.
I'm confused about all this .
**I just don't* have the budget to buy a MAC and i want to do APP development just (Debugging ) deployment will be done latter please tell me what should i do or give me the proper instruction thanks.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run Xcode on a mac to build Xamarin apps for iOS. A Windows install of Xamarin on Visual Studio will allow you to connect to a mac to do the build remotely, but you still need a mac available that has Xcode installed on it to do the build.

You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store. You will also need the mac to upload the final package to the iOS App Store if you're going to release it there.

An other option is to use a cloud based Mac server, there are several companies that rent them out on hourly/monthly basis for this purpose ([MacinCloud](http://macincloud.com) being one that I've heard of).

Comment: okay what if i install mac osx in vmware then install xcode on it then on native windows i connect my ( mac hosted in vmware ) to my xamarin visual studio windows?

Comment: @SaifAli That would work, if you got the vm to work with macOS; it is known to have issues, as macOS is only designed to run on Apple hardware.

Comment: @vrwim Thanks for the quick reply okay i got everything under control now , just last question , so when i keep my vmware running mac os then will the windows xamarin visual studio mac finder be able to identify the vmware mac ? or do i need to go for another round?

Comment: You should also bear in mind that Apple's licensing expressly forbids OSX being installed on anything other than Apple hardware.  Your solution would be unsupported and contravening their license

Comment: If you get a VMware image working and networked it should behave exactly like a mac on your LAN so xamarin should connect and do the build.  I doubt they officially support this configuration either though.

Comment: @SaifAli you might need to fiddle with the network settings, find one that makes the VM act like it's on the same LAN as the host computer (I think there's one for that). Also bear in mind what Russell says, this solution might have issues as it is not supported.

Comment: @Russell i am aware of that caution but who cares , i just want to do a little bad (if i'm not wrong illegal ), but since i'm just doing it for development for my own not for commercial one.A lot of people are hosting mac images on VMware so no issues .

Comment: @vrwim Yes i will create a network switch so that it will act as on the same lan i got it thanks will keep you guys updated.

Comment: @SaifAli - sure - your choice just wanted to highlight it in case you weren't aware :-)

Comment: @Russell That's nice of you pal.

Comment: @vrwim Plus should i go for Vmware or Hyper-V (Official Microsft)?

Comment: @SaifAli I have no idea, I don't really know much about virtual machines. You could always ask another question if you have a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

XCode needs and can only be installed onto a MAC OSX system.

Once you have XCode installed, you can use its iPhone simulator to emulate the iOS apps you make on your windows pc.

You need to connect to the MAC by using the MAC Agent on Visual Studio. This connects remotely to the MAC and allows you to debug the app to be emulated onto the virtual iOS device being simulated on your MAC OSX system.

You can use MAC Cloud based server but also, you can use a real iOS device such as an iPhone to debug apps directly onto the device.